# Data cleaning requirement in hdfs file

Tags: scala, hive

I have a CSV file like below for which i need to apply data cleaning technique in hadoop. The file contains hundreds of thousands of records but I gave only 4 records for easiness.

```
field1,field2,field3,field4
1,abc,def,ghi
4,ijk,
,lmn
5,,opq,rst
8,
uvw,,xyz
10,hjg,jsh,nbm
```

And i want the output result as

```
field1,field2,field3,field4
1,abc,def,ghi
4,ijk,,lmn
5,,opq,rst
8,uvw,,xyz
10,hjg,jsh,nbm
```

I am new to hadoop. What is the best,easy and optimal way to do in Hadoop? Is it doable in Hive?

Once this is achieved, if there are any special characters i need to replace them with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your records in different lines like this?
4,ijk,
,lmn

What I can think of(if you know scala well) is,

Create a flatmap on top of the CSV file.
Split on comma

For loop - Move data into arrays of 4 element,

As soon as you reached 4th, go to next line

Comment: Yes, that us what our main problem is. The data will not be in a single record for a customer as the data is coming from CSV file filling manually by front end.Can we do it using scala as I haven't worked on scala before.

Comment: Yup. It's very easy in scala.  It can be done probably in 5-6 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks alot Sagar for the guidance. I will try at my end as well though I need to start scala from scratch. Though it is wrong, if you could help me with some code snippets, it will lead me to right path.Thank you in advance